# Will Sqldatareader with Using Statement ever return an Output parameter?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parameters, sqldatareader, using-statement

Here's a simple code snippet of a larger function as an example.

```
Using conn as New SqlConnection("conn string")
    Using find as new SqlCommand("ExampleProc",conn)
        Dim rParam as new SqlParameter("@RESULT",SqlDbType.Int)
        rParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        find.Pareameters.Add(rParam)

        Using f as SqlDataReader = find.ExecuteReader
              'Do stuff with datareader
        End Using

        updateResult.Success = Convert.ToBoolean(find.Parameters("@RESULT").Value)
    End Using
  End Using
```

I know the Output parameter is returned after the SqlDataReader is closed.  From what I think I know, the Using statement will call `.Dispose` on the SqlDataReader, so will that basically wipe out the Output parameter?  If so, what is the best method to call a SqlDataReader that also contains Output parameters that closes and disposes everything correctly?  I couldn't find any specific info or examples online in my searching.  Thanks!

---

Let me add that based on what I've read you only have access to the Output parameter using a SqlDataReader after you call .Close on the SqlDataReader.

Comment: Disposing the reader should only affect that one object (and any objects or resources it owns). I think it shouldn't remove anything from the command.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need the *value* returned in the output parameter.

You can copy the value to a variable declared outside the `Using` block and return that, or return the value directly, as soon as you have access to it.

Comment: Based on what I've read, you only have access to the value if you call .close on the sqldatareader. So will it be returned in the above example to use in the first place?  I know how to reference and use the value in the rest of the function.

Comment: @NinjaBomb - From the article: "I found that you must completely process the entire recordset BEFORE retrieving the output parameters otherwise, the output params will be empty." - this means all records need to be read first, not that `.Close()` needs to be called.

Comment: A short copy and paste summary from the end of the article: -Make sure you retrieve the recordset first as an SqlDataReader via cmd.ExecuteReader() -Process through all recordsets and then... **-Make sure you CLOSE the recordset, or SqlDataReader via reader.Close() before trying to retrieve the output parameters.**

Answer (score 0):

not sure that I understand what you want to achieve but this seems a better approach

```
    updateResult.Success = False

    Using f as SqlDataReader = find.ExecuteReader
          'Do stuff with datareader
          updateResult.Success = Convert.ToBoolean(find.Parameters("@RESULT").Value)
    End Using
```

You read the result within the `Using` statement and if anything fails you preset it to false...

Comment: I thought your example would not work because the SqlDataReader must be closed before you can access the output parameter?  Do you close it in the Using statement first?

Comment: why must the reader be closed first ? I don't work with sql sever but with other DBs (like oracle) never had such a limitation...

Comment: Check this blog post out for good explanation: http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/8/output-parameters-and-recordsets-from-a-stored-procedure

Comment: I understand... that is different with Oracle - there you could just return a cursor and work with that... this just means that before you read the output param you need to have read all records (for example with a while loop within the Using)... the above would still work...

Comment: That's exactly what I do to retrieve the records in the Using block.  Not so sure the Output parameter will be available though. Hopefully doing some testing today